# Autoupgradeenable property of openfiledialog

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-2.0, openfiledialog, filedialog

I had need of showing open file dialog in winform application. And one property of the file dialog, **autoupgradeenabled** which I set as a **true**, which is for updating the open file dialog according to operating system, like if application is running on xp then dialog is displayed different as in wista or window 7.

So when I used that property as a **true**, and once in the machine where there was **xp with 2.0 .net framework** that open file dialog could not be opened. So I tried by doing it false then also it could not be opened in the machine with the **xp and 2.0 framework.**

Then I tried by commenting that whole line means I removed that property from the code, then I tried and it was fine in xp machine with 2.0 framework. So problem is I cannot understand that why that property is not working by setting it false or true. Because by setting that property is should work in all os with all framework and dialog should be changed according to os. If not,then what is the meaning of that property ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It didn't work because the `AutoUpgradeEnabled` property wasn't added until .NET 2.0 SP1.**

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.autoupgradeenabled.aspx) for that property lists the supported versions as:

> .NET Framework:                       versions 4, 3.5 SP1, 3.0 SP1, 2.0 SP1
>   .NET Framework Client Profile:  versions 4, 3.5 SP1

Prior to version 2.0 SP1, the `OpenFileDialog` and `SaveFileDialog` were automatically displayed using the new, Windows Vista-style dialogs. The ability to opt out of this with the `AutoUpgradeEnabled` property wasn't added until later. ([MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397813.aspx)) This wasn't a breaking change because the *default* setting for that property remained "True" when it was added to later versions.

According to [Brandon Turner's blog entry on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brandonturner/archive/2008/03/13/wow-that-s-pretty-and-easy-autoupgradeenabled-for-open-file-dialog.aspx), you'll get a [`MissingMethodException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.missingmethodexception.aspx) when trying to use it on an earlier version of the Framework. Thus, by trying to set the property (to either True *or* False), you caused the program to throw an exception. Commenting and removing that line allowed everything to work fine, just as you described.

Comment: Thakns.. +1 for  the great answer.